# Does a mov instruction that involve memory access get done slower than mov between registers

Tags: performance, caching, cpu-architecture

Consider the best case of memory access from L1 Cache. It will typically take 4 cpu cycles (referred from [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-manycore-testing-lab/topic/287236)) while register access takes one cpu cycle.
So simply compare the mov instruction between register e.g. "movl %eax,%ebx" with mov instruction with memory involvement "movl (%eax),%ebx", does it always take 4 cycles or so more for the latter than for the former? If so, what is the CPU doing when waiting for the memory data?

Answer (score 1):

The register to register mov takes 0.5 clocks (the unit that executes the mov instruction has a throughput of 2 instructions / clock and a latency of one clock cycle).

In the memory-fetch case the micro-op to perform the fetch has been despatched to to the execution-unit on the CPU and is waiting for the data to arrive. What the CPU is doing in this interval depends on the program being executed. If there are other instructions in the stream that are not data-dependent on the fetch from memory then they will be executing in parallel. If every following instruction is dependent on this piece of data (in the window in the instruction stream) then the CPU will stall waiting for the data to arrive.

If you are interested in how this works in more detail, check out Agner Fog's [resources](http://agner.org/optimize/), but in particular his experiments on instruction timing available [here](http://agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf).

Comment: Many thanks for the reply and resources. They are of much help for me. So if the micro-op (say uop1) to perform fetch fully functions (e.g. the data has no dependency on the preceding instructions), the cpu can wait much less (than 4 cycles which is L1 cache latency) before it is executing micro-op (say uop2) that loads the data get ready by uop1 to the target register. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: How about memory write instructions e.g. "movl %eax, (%ebx)". Any preview on that? How does the micro-op work for those momory write instructions?

Comment: I think that the fetch uop will take the minimum fetch latency to the cache (e.g. 4 cycles). The register rename to expose the temporary register to the programmer is a half-stage in the pipeline (the results are forwarded) so it takes 0.5 clocks. This is the time that you see if you write micro-benchmarks to time the uops. The movl %eax, (%ebx) will use the store unit rather than fetch, so it probably dispatches in 0.5 clocks if the value in ebx is known (but the results won't hit the cache until later).